# Kotlin Cast String as String.Companion

Tags: string, casting, kotlin

So I'm new to learning Kotlin, coming from a C# background. I've been messing around with types and a few other things. I'm trying to create a static class of "WalMartGreeters" that can add greeters to a list, and then call a simple static function to display those. My method(s) takes a string argument/string list to add to the mutable string list but when I attempt to add values to it. I get a pre-compilation error saying "expected String.Companion" "got String" I attempt to change it to cast the String as a String.Companion and then it says the cast is illegal.

The predominant error I get is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.internal.StringCompanionObject

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {
    walMartGreeter.addTo("Jean")
    walMartGreeter.addTo("Dale")
    walMartGreeter.addTo("Phil")
    walMartGreeter.addTo("Chris")
    walMartGreeter.listTheWholeFam()
}

class walMartGreeter(val strName:String) {
    companion object classList {
        var prntList = mutableListOf(String)

        fun addTo(strNameToAdd:String) {
            prntList.add(strNameToAdd)
        }

        fun addTo(listOfNames:List<String>) {
            for (item in listOfNames) {
                prntList.add(item)
            }
        }

        fun listTheWholeFam() {
            //println("All I do is $strName")
            for(item in prntList) {
                println("Hello, $item!")
            }
            //println("type of mutList: ${mutList.ToString()}")
            if(prntList is MutableList) {
                println("Yeah, it's a mutableList");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :), replace the `prntList = mutableListOf(String)` with the `prntList = mutableListOf<String>()`, you initialized `prntList` with a `MutableList<StringCompanionObject>` rather than a `MutableList<String>`.

Comment: That did it, but why? And why was I able to initialize it as mutableListOf(String) without a syntax error? Why would it by default cast MutableList(String) as... String.Companion? Was that because it was inside a Companion Object?

Comment: No, a compile error  is reported for `prntList.add(strNameToAdd)` . what's editor you are using?

Comment: Well that's true, but that's because it couldn't cast a Java.String to Kotlin.String.Companion or w/e, why did it show up as String.Companion by default? I'm using IntelliJ on Ubuntu. Also, I can type in the correction, but would rather give it to you <3 but I can't because it's a comment :X

Comment: Like, why does :: var prntList = mutableListOf(String) :: not work. Within intelliJ IDE it will give the error in the companion functions saying that a String was given but a String.Companion item is required. Why does mutableListOf<String>() work but not mutableListOf(String)?

Comment: Names have multiple meanings. `String`, when used inside `<>` or after `:`, means the *type*. `String`, when used as a callable, means the constructor. `String`, when used as a value, means the companion object, which holds static methods such as `String.format()`. `mutableListOf(String)` means a list with one element, the (singleton) `String` companion object, which is not actually a `String`. `mutableListOf<String>()` means an empty mutable list with elements of type `String`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the code above in your question can't be compiled since the `prntList` is a `MutableList<String.Companion>` rather than a `MutableList<String>`. IF you want the `prntList` to adds `String`s, you need to change its type  to `MutableList<String>`, for example:

```
var prntList = mutableListOf<String>()
```

Secondly, the `String` in `mutableListOf(String)` is just an **qualifier** rather than a class. which means the `String` will be reference to a specific reference in its scope. in your case the *qualifier* will reference to its [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).

> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the **qualifier**.

For example:

```
//                         v--- reference to its companion object
val it:String.Companion = String
```

On the other hand, you also can make the *qualifier* reference to a top-level variable, for example:

```
 val String = ""
 //                            v--- reference to the top-level variable
 var prntList = mutableListOf(String)
 //  ^---is a `MutableList<String>` rather than `MutableList<String.Companion>` now
```

The different between the `mutableListOf<String>()` and the `mutableListOf(String)` as below:

```
//             v--- it is a type argument of the `String` class
mutableListOf<String>()

//             v--- it is a qualifier that reference to `String.Companion`
mutableListOf(String)
```